# Is getComputedStyle() only way to get style set by css in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have element, which looks like this:

```
<div
    class="bar__indicator"
    [ngStyle]="{'width': passwordScorePercent + '%'}"
    [ngClass]="{'bar__indicator--weak': !isStrongEnough, 'bar__indicator--strong': isStrongEnough}"></div>
```

then, depending on class, a background color gets applied.

When i check for this color in test, I get empty value when checking nativeElement style property, as it is only for inline styling. Is doing getComputedStyle(nativeElement) the only way to check such things? Or should I do it differently?

Comment: You may need to call `fixture.detectChanges()` manually in order for DOM to be updated in test.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota i did it of course, but still, .styles property does not contain things affected by css.

Comment: can you create stackblitz